# How can I identify english language text using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

I have some data on YouTube channel descriptions which are quite messy as you'd imagine. I'd like to filter channels whose description is in English, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here's a sample of what the data looks like

```sql
WITH

foo AS (
  SELECT ".olá sejam muito bem vindos. este canal foi criado" AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "Hello, I am Abhy and welcome to my channel." AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "Channels I love:  Labrant Fam, Norris Nuts, La Familia Diamond, Piper Rockelle" AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "हेलो दोस्तो  रमेश और सागर और सुखदेव आपका स्वागत करते हैं इस चैनल के ऊपर" AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "Hi, I'm K-POP RANDOM === KPOP RANDOM DANCE === I hope you can enjoy" AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Public TV Kannada news channel. The slogan is "Yaara Aasthiyoo Alla, Idu Nimma TV"' AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "Instagram: www.instagram.com/whatsfordinner5291/" AS x
  UNION ALL SELECT "Welcome to RunningBoy12, a gaming channel brought to you by RO!" as x
)

select * from foo
```

My idea is to hand-label some records, measure the frequency of foreign characters and words, and then fit a logistic regression model to the data using [BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#model_type). Is there a better way?

Comment: I answered to your question. @Ben

Comment: If you show us your GCP architecture drawing(like how to collect youtube data, etc), I can do help more precisely in terms of GCP architecture. In this current question, we have few clues to advice you.

Comment: Hi @Ben, For your requirement, I would suggest you use Google Cloud Storage to store the data and then use Dataflow to filter the data and upload it to BigQuery. After you upload the data , you can use BigQuery ML for applying the model. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: BTW, this question is not about the code but about cloud architecture.

Comment: @RyoMatsuzaka I saw your answer. (No need to make a comment about it.) I'm not sure why it got downvoted. I upvoted it. But I'm waiting to see if others chime in with a more native BigQuery solution.

Comment: The reason why I got downvoted from someone could be my first answer was a little short. I added some comments to my answer after I got downvoted. Then upvoted by you, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect language with Cloud Translation API. Before inserting records, you need to run this API. You may want to use Cloud Functions to call this API. Or if you want to do more complicated ETL, you may use Cloud Dataflow.

When a text is categorized as English, you shall insert record to any DB you want.
In this way, you don't have to store non-English text in your DB, and can save your money for storage and querying. Instead of BigQuery, CloudFirestore could be option. It depends on the service you want to achieve.

Here is Cloud Translation API document:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/detecting-language-v3#before_you_begin

Comparizon of DB:
https://db-engines.com/en/system/Amazon+DocumentDB%3BGoogle+BigQuery%3BGoogle+Cloud+Firestore

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is somewhat smaller (<10MB), you can quickly get similar result by exporting to Google Sheets and using the `DETECTLANGUAGE`-function instead of using any API.

1. Run the query in BigQuery
2. Export result to Google Sheets
3. Add a column with `=DETECTLANGUAGE(<column/row to detect>`

More information about the `DETECTLANGUAGE`-function here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093278?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty one:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(x, r'\b(the|and|or|is|am|are)\b')
```

This might be suitable if you have specific words you believe would only appear in English text. You can put some specific words in the regex relevant to your context to improve the accuracy. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  regexp_replace(x, r'[[:ascii:]]|[\p{S}]', r'') = '' as English,
from foo
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Logic is simple - you remove all ASCII and Symbols and the if anything left  - this is a good indication of non-English